# Ansible: How to test a registered variable for conditional?

Tags: centos7, ansible, file-permissions

Attempting to use Ansible for locate and change all file ownership for user_01 to user_02?

```
  - name: "Find files for user_01 or UID of user_01_uid"
    command: "find / -path /proc -prune -o -path /sys -prune -o  \\( -user user_01 \\) -o  \\( -uid user_01_uid \\)"
    # escape character "\" prior to backslash character "\"   \\. Spacing to work with Ansible CentOS 7
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: files_2_change

  - name: "Display files_2_change"
    debug:
      msg: "{{ files_2_change.stdout_lines }}"

  - name: "Change owner & group permissions"
    file: 
      path: "{{ files_2_change.stdout_lines }}"
      owner: user_02
      group: user_02
      mode: 0760
      modification_time: preserve   # now
    when: 
      - files_2_change != '/proc'
      - files_2_change != '/sys'


    # Better soln for chown
    # command: "chown -h -R --from=user_01:user_01 user_02:user_02 {{ files_2_change.stdout_lines }}"
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to perform the conditional check on the entire `files_2_change` variable, when what you're really interested in is doing the conditional check on each element of the list you're iterating over. Unfortunately, because of [how Ansible processes conditionals in loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_conditionals.html#loops-and-conditionals), you can't just loop over the `file` module and do the check each time.

My recommendation would be to add an additional processing task before the actual `file` task to drop the undesired paths using a python list comprehension:

```
- name: "Process files_2_change, dropping unwanted files"
  set_fact:
    processed_files_2_change: >
      {{ processed_files_2_change | default([]) +
        [ item ] if '/proc' not in item and '/sys' not in item else []
      }}
  loop: "{{ files_2_change.stdout_lines }}"

- name: "Change owner & group permissions"
  file: 
    path: "{{ item }}"
    owner: user_02
    group: user_02
    mode: 0760
    modification_time: preserve
  loop: "{{ processed_files_2_change }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute *path* in the module [file](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/file_module.html#file-manage-files-and-file-properties) requires string. A list should fail.

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected ')'. String: {{ files_2_change.stdout_lines ))"}

(the same way with *processed_files_2_change*)

It's possible to loop the list instead.

```
- name: "Change owner & group permissions"
  file: 
    path: "{{ item }}"
    owner: user_02
    group: user_02
    mode: 0760
    modification_time: preserve   # now              
  loop: "{{ files_2_change.stdout_lines }}"
  when: 
    - item is not search('^/proc')
    - item is not search('^/sys')
```

(not tested)

Notes

- Use [find](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/find_module.html#find-return-a-list-of-files-based-on-specific-criteria) instead of "command: "find ..."
- If there are directories in *files_2_change.stdout_lines* the mode *mode: 0760* will make them not accessible for the group.

Comment: Good catch! This is a good idea and Ive updated my answer to loop over the file module!

Comment: Use find instead of "command: "find ..."

Sorry but reading the Find module link sent, I do not see a criteria for owner.  Am I misunderstanding something in the docs like possibly "pattern" or something?

Comment: @Bryan: you are right, the find module does not let you search by owner and you are in a case where using the command makes sense (until the ansible guys implement the feature which would make sense as well).

Answer (score 0):

Update: This is what I've got so far following feedback here (July 17, 2019).

Added /var/spool/mail to the exclusions.

Current testings seems to work.

```
  - name: "Find files for user_X or UID of user_X_uid"
    command: "find / -path /proc -prune -o -path /sys -prune -o  \\( -user user01 \\) -o  \\( -uid 1051 \\)"
    ignore_errors: yes
    register: files_2_change


  - name: "Change owner & group permissions"
    file: 
      path: "{{ item }}"
      owner: user02
      group: user02
      mode: 0771          # If there are directories - 0760 will make them not accessible for the group.
      modification_time: preserve
    loop: "{{ files_2_change.stdout_lines }}"
    when: 
      - item is not search('^/proc')
      - item is not search('^/sys')
      - item is not search('^/var/spool/mail')
```

Thank you to everyone for your input and help!